# What are the counterparts in Wolfram to left and right division of a matrix in other programming language, e.g. Julia and MATLAB?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, inverse, function-comparison

Sometimes, to find the inverse of a matrix is a labor-consuming task, or even "disgusting", especially when the matrix is "ill". It is said, e.g. in Julia, that the left/right division operation is more stable than the bare `inv`. So, does there exist a similar functionality in *Mathematica*?

Of very close relation, there are at least three functions that deal with matrix inversion in Wolfram: `Inverse`, `PseudoInverse` and `LinearSolve` (`LinearSolve[#, IdentityMatrix[Length[#]]] &`). Then according to what principles can one make the decision choosing which to use?

---

**Update**

The answers make me somewhat "embarrassed" because they all are very informative and instructive so that it is difficult to choose one to make a green tick.

Comment: The [Julia documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/linalg/) has some info on what criteria they use to determine which algorithm to use. I think the closest to that is `LinearSolve`, which also chooses the best algorithm (`Method`) depending on the type of matrix you give to it.

Comment: The pseudoinverse, aka the [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse), is not exactly the same as the inverse. If you need the inverse, use `Inverse`. If `LinearSolve` would be the way to go, clearly this is how `Inverse` would have been implemented.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how-to-solve-xa-b-matrix-which-i-need-x](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144207/how-to-solve-xa-b-matrix-which-i-need-x)

Comment: I've been wishing someone would emphasize that `LinearSolve[A, b]` is the closest *Mathematica* equivalent to `A \ b`, other than in a link.  But it doesn't seem worth a new answer....

Comment: You forget `LeastSquares[]` in your list. Use that if you don't have square matrices, but you want a minimum norm solution to your linear equation.

Comment: @J.M. It was not forgotten, but in fact I had not known it. But it is plausibly included in "at least". Anyway, thank you for letting me hear of it.

Answer (score 22):

I just stumbled upon it! At least when storing the factorization in a `LinearSolveFunction` object, we can use it for the transposed solve by supplying a further (not documented?) string variable to it:
When calling `sol[b, 1234]` with a `LinearSolveFunction` object `sol`, Mathematica tells us that it only accepts the strings `"N"`, `"T"`, `"C"`, and `"J"`. As it is the LAPACK standard, `"N"` means solving with **n**o transposition and `"T"` means solving with **t**ransposition. `"C"` means conjugate transpose, and `"J"` means conjugate (maybe because `"J"` is a reflection of `"C"` in the same way as the transpose of a matrix is its reflection along the main diagonal?). Here a usage example:

```
SeedRandom[123];
n = 5;
A = RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, {n, n}];
b = RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, {n}];
sol = LinearSolve[A];
x = sol[b];
y = sol[b, "T"];
z = sol[b, "C"];
w = sol[b, "J"];

Max[Abs[A.x - b]]
Max[Abs[y.A - b]]
Max[Abs[z.Conjugate[A] - b]]
Max[Abs[Conjugate[A].w - b]]
```

> 3.33067*10^-16
>
> 4.8473*10^-16
>
> 4.44089*10^-16
>
> 3.14018*10^-16

**A word of warning:**

This seems to work with LAPACK as backend for dense matrices and with UMFPACK (`Method->"Multifrontal"`) and the nonsymmetric iterative solvers (`Method->{"Krylov",Method->"GMRES"` and `Method->{"Krylov",Method->"BiCGSTAB"`) as backend for sparse matrices but **not** with the (also almost undocumented) Pardiso solver (`Method->"Pardiso"`), although Pardiso  has these capabilities and although it would have been easy to implement it...

Comment: Undocumented? Things are becoming more interesting! BTW, a natural question arises as where to find the documentation of undocumented usages/features?

Comment: @AlexanderZeng That's the sad truth: The API for the various linear solvers are rarely documented. If found this feature by pure luck due to a typo and recalled that there was this open question...

Answer (score 21):

The [documentation](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html) for MATLAB's `mrdivide` states that

> The operators / and \ are related to each other by the equation B/A =
>   (A'\B')'

In light of this we may write:

```
LinearSolve[Transpose[A], b]
```

This question was also answered by Daniel Lichtblau [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/b8UgFm_WBiY/GBeyrOHl05oJ).

The equivalency follows from the following two [properties of the transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose):
$$
\left(A^\mathrm{-1}\right)^\mathrm{T} = \left(A^\mathrm{T}\right)^\mathrm{-1},\quad \left(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}\right)^\mathrm{T}=\mathbf{B}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{A}^\mathrm{T}
$$
We can show it like this:
$$
x\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{B}\Leftrightarrow x = \mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\Leftrightarrow x^\mathrm{T}=\left(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\right)^\mathrm{T}=\left(\mathbf{A}^{-1}\right)^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{B}^\mathrm{T}=\left(\mathbf{A}^{\mathrm{T}}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{B}^\mathrm{T}\\ \Leftrightarrow \mathbf{A}^\mathrm{T}x^\mathrm{T} = \mathbf{B}^\mathrm{T}
$$

Due to the way Mathematica handles the concept of row and column vectors, we do not need to use `Transpose` on vectors. This leads to the solution above.

Comment: Still, this requires the transposition of the matrix `A`. Even more severe: If `A` has already been factorized (e.g., LU-factorization with `LinearSolve[A]`), the `Transpose[A]` had to be factorized, again.  This can be a performance issue (in particular with UMFPACK that is used as the default for `SparseArrays`. But common direct solvers based on LU-decomposition (LAPACK, Pardiso...) also provide a solver for the transpose that reuses the first factorization of `A`. What's merely lacking (as far as I know) is a user working interface for that.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Yes, Pardiso's API is underutilized. (And the Pardiso method is not documented yet.) However, this is not very surprising from such a high-level language as WL. Other considerations than such performance considerations take precedence.

Comment: The author in Weisberg, S. (2014). Applied Linear Regression (Fourth ed.). Hoboken, NJ: John Wiley & Sons. worries much about introducing rounding errors in inverting the (X'X) matrix, which can be quite large and ill-conditioned, while solving a linear regression problem.  At minimum he recommends subtracting the column mean from each column observation (of X) to make all the values relatively the same size.  In Appendix A.9 he suggests using the QR algorithm instead of Inverse, and in Appendix A.10 using spectral decomposition instead of Inverse.  He claims most statistical packages do this.

Comment: @CElliott I think there is a misunderstanding of what this answer does. The point of this answer is indeed that it solves xA = b without explicitly inverting A, which is not desirable for various reason. It achieves this by using `LinearSolve`. How `LinearSolve` solves the problem depends on the method chosen, but a decomposition such as the QR decomposition or the Cholesky decomposition will probably be involved, yes.

Comment: @CElliott Here is [an apology for `inv(A)*b`](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.6035).  Note that for regression, one would probably use `LinearModelFit`, whose methods are unknown to me but seem to never lose to QR on random examples (the SS for `LinearModelFit` are sometimes a couple of machine epsilon less than QR).

Comment: @Michael, `LinearModelFit[]` (and `Fit[]`, and `FindFit[]` in the linear case) all use SVD, which is definitely much more stable (tho more expensive) than QR for least squares.

Answer (score 13):

Henrik has already written on the *undocumented* second argument of a `LinearSolveFunction[]`, so let me just put out a short demo wrapper showing how to use the built-in, but *undocumented* LAPACK routines to solve a linear equation, given the output of `LUDecomposition[]`:

```
Options[backsub] = {Mode -> Automatic};
backsub[lu_, perm_, opts : OptionsPattern[]][rhs_] := Module[{xx = rhs, piv, switch},
    piv = LinearAlgebra`LAPACK`PermutationToPivot[perm];
    switch = Switch[OptionValue[Mode],
                    Normal | Automatic, "N",
                    Transpose, "T",
                    ConjugateTranspose, "C",
                    _, "N"];
    LinearAlgebra`LAPACK`GETRS[switch, lu, piv, xx]; xx]
```

For example, after using `LUDecomposition[]` as usual,

```
mat = N[{{1, 2 - I, 3}, {1 + 4 I, 5, 6 + 3 I}, {7 - 5 I, 8 - 2 I, 9}}];
{lu, perm, cond} = LUDecomposition[mat]
   {{{7. - 5. I, 8. - 2. I, 9. + 0. I},
     {-0.175676 + 0.445946 I, 5.51351 - 3.91892 I, 7.58108 - 1.01351 I},
     {0.0945946 + 0.0675676 I, 0.249262 - 0.0679268 I, 0.32782 + 0.15948 I}},
    {3, 2, 1}, 115.139}
```

we can do this:

```
new = {{14 - 2 I, 24 - 7 I, 24 + 7 I},
       {29 + 13 I, 36 - 7 I, 36 + 7 I},
       {50 - 9 I, 42 + 6 I, 42 - 6 I}};

bs = backsub[lu, perm];
bs[new] // Chop
   {{1., -3.2 + 7.4 I, -8.8 + 4.6 I},
    {2., -25.4 + 3.4 I, -25. - 32.2 I},
    {3., 24.8667 - 15.5333 I, 38.3333 + 13.9333 I}}

bsh = backsub[lu, perm, Mode -> ConjugateTranspose];
bsh[new] // Chop
   {{40.1333 - 9.2 I, -21.8 + 74.4 I, 1.},
    {-6.86667 + 0.466667 I, 13.2 - 17.6 I, 2.},
    {-3.4 - 0.533333 I, 9. - 8. I, 3.}}

bst = backsub[lu, perm, Mode -> Transpose];
bst[new] // Chop
   {{23.9333 - 115.4 I, 1., -21.8 - 74.4 I},
    {2.93333 + 32.9333 I, 2., 13.2 + 17.6 I},
    {6.6 + 14.5333 I, 3., 9. + 8. I}}
```