# Analogies to Help New Users

Tags: programming, functional-style, education

In many of the classes that I teach, I require students to learn the basics of Mathematica which we use throughout the semester to do computations and to submit homeworks (in notebook form). Some students really like this and some... not so much.

Since I teach in an engineering department, almost everyone already knows some programming language: *Matlab*, *python*, *java*, or *C* are the most common, though there is quite a variety. One thing that I have found pretty effective is to try and relate Mathematica formalisms, structures, and ideas to those that students already know. For example:

$-$ When talking about using the [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) Attribute of functions, I compare this to Matlab's [vectorization](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html)

$-$ When talking about alternatives for loops, Mathematica's [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) function is analogous to python's [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), for example, observe the similarity between

```
squares = [x**2 for x in range(10)]
```

and

```
squares = Table[x^2, {x, Range[10]}]
```

$-$ Mathematica's Notebook format is analogous to [Jupyter notebooks](https://jupyter.org/index.html) which merge word processing, computation, and interactive presentations.

My question is this: What are some other analogies between Mathematica functions, expressions, and structures that might be helpful to new users in understanding "what Mathematica is thinking" or "why it works that way"?

Update: It seems that we have some very good answers for Matlab and for python. How about other languages? Any nice analogies for/with other popular languages?

Comment: Do you have materials from your courses that you could make available?   Much obliged.

Comment: I do... I teach courses in "Signals and Systems" and in "Image Processing". If these would be helpful, email me at sound401@gmail and I can get you the materials. Neither of these is "instruction in Mathematica" -- rather, they use Mathematica as a vehicle for teaching the subject matter of the classes.

Comment: It is the other way around: Jupyter notebooks are (still poor) analogs of Mathematica notebooks.

Comment: @AntonAntonov -- some students have used Jupyter notebooks in previous semesters -- for them, Mathematica notebooks provide a familiar environment.

Comment: @bills I was half-joking, referring to the historical time-line of notion and implementation of "computational notebook". You are referring to the exposure time-lines of individuals/students.

Comment: I would say "abandon" Mathematica and switch to python, or more specifically, Jupiter notebooks to conduct such classroom-level computations. it is obvious that  in your case analogies can be easily made to convert pupils to a new language; so why not make them stay with python and sharpen their python skills? Personally, I love Mathematica to death. However, to be pragmatic, python is way more widely used and provides much easier gateways to many new worlds, in particular in the recent ~2 years. I feel rather reluctant

Comment: @sunt05 some percentage of the students in my class feel the same way. But the class is not about learning Mathematica or learning python, but about image processing. One thing python lacks is the easy interactivity of Mathematica, which is really key when examining many different variations on parameters, filters, and processing methods. I'd be happy to see an answer from you with more python-esque analogies

Comment: Perhaps analogies are more harmful than helpful beyond a certain point. They might encourage students to think in Python and try to translate their Python solution directly to Mathematica. That often results in a hideously complex and inefficient solution. An alternative approach would be to show how certain basic tasks are accomplished. Describe those basic tasks in English, not in Python. The tasks should be chosen based on what is taught in your course, and what mistakes student most commonly made in past years.

Comment: @Szabolcs -- it is certainly true that even the best intentioned methods can go awry. Introductory programming courses often stress For loops so much that students don't even realize there are alternatives. By pointing out that they may already know an alternative to the evil For (either via vectorization in Matlab or list completion in python) they may be able to avoid Fors unpleasant complexity. And yes... it is a constantly evolving landscape -- when I first started teaching courses in Mathematica, python was not part of the scene.

Answer (score 29):

Imho some important things to translate between *Matlab* and *Mathematica*:

- "everything is a matrix (or inefficient)" vs. "everything is an expression"
- indexing into arrays: `:` vs. `All` or `;;`
- indexing into arrays: `j:i:k` vs. `j;;k;;i`
- constructing ranges:  `j:i:k` vs. `Range[j,k,i]`
- column-major vs. row-major: `mat(:)` vs. `Flatten[Transpose[mat]]` or `(mat')(:)` vs. `Flatten`
- combining tensors: `cat` vs. `Join` and `ArrayFlatten`
- anonymous functions: `@(x) x^2` vs.  `#^2&` or `x \[Function] x^2`
- building simple tensors: `zeroes`, `ones` vs. `ConstantArray`
- more tensors: `eye` and `speye` vs. `IdentityMatrix` and 
  `IdentityMatrix[#,SparseArray]&`
- `diag` and `spdiags` vs. `DiagonalMatrix` and `DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[#]] &` / `SparseArray` together with `Band` (but also `diag` vs. `Diagonal` btw.)
- even more tensors: `rand` vs. `RandomReal`
- loops: `for` vs. `Do`, `Table`, `Array`, and `Map` (and not `For`!!11eleven)
- `arrayfun` and `cellfun` vs. `Map` (with level spec `{-1}`) (special thanks to mikado for pointing out this one)
- `while` and `repeat` vs. `While`, but also `NestWhile`, `NestWhileList`, `FixedPoint`, and `FixedPointList`
- `if ... else ... end` vs. `If`
- `if ... elseif... elseif... end` vs. `Which`
- `piecewise` vs., well, `Piecewise`
- solving linear systems: `\` and `/`  vs. `LinearSolve` and `LinearSolve[#1][#2, "T"] &` (for details, see also [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161818))
- more linear systems: `pinv` vs. `LeastSquares` and `PseudoInverse`
- `struct` vs. `Association`
- `cell` vs. `List`

Certainly less important

- `kron` vs. `KroneckerProduct`
- `meshgrid` vs. `Tuples` (Due to the intuitive plotting in *Mathematica*, `Tuples` within *Mathematica* has not nearly the same importance as `meshgrid` has within *Matlab*.)
- classes vs. tags (`TagSet` and `TagSetDelayed`) (though each Matlab programmer I've ever met refused to use classes...)
- `isa` vs. `Head` and patterns
- `mex` vs. `Compile` (and LibraryLink for the pro users)

Comment: One could also mention `Piecewise` in the context of `If` and `Which`...

Comment: @kirma Good point. I added it, but compared it to `piecewise` rather than to `if`. ;)

Comment: Is `IdentityMatrix[@,SparseArray]&` intended to be `IdentityMatrix[#,SparseArray]&`? Might also be worthwhile to point out `DiagonalMatrix`, though I don't recall if there's a clear Matlab analog.

Comment: @eyorble Good point. Corrected it. There are als `diag` and `spdiags` in _Matlab_.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Ah. I've never used Matlab. ;)

Comment: You could add `arrayfun`/`cellfun` vs `Map`

Comment: @mikado Yeah, I recall to have used that heavily in the few Matlab projects that I was lucky to do... Thanks for the hint! I added it.

Answer (score 9):

When a language, e.g., Python, not emphasizing but has to talk about "functional programming", usually it speaks about three functions: `map`, `filter` and `reduce`. I always think comparison a good approach to learn things, so below I share the comparison I made before.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Besides, `Function (&)` vs `lambda`, `Array, Table` vs "list comprehensions" (`Table` has been mentioned but `Range[]` is redundant.).

Comment: I think if you want to talk correspondence, the *entirety* of itertools is big. It provides a slew of utilities that Mathematica has, but does so in a more efficient lazy fashion.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Why are they more efficient?

Answer (score 6):

For those with experience in python, WRI has already provided [a nice introductory tutorial](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) along with many analogies.

However, for the class intended for image processing as mentioned by the OP, pure python is for certain not enough: [`numpy`](https://www.numpy.org), [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org), [`scipy`](https://www.scipy.org) and [`pillow`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io) are some of the essential packages to go with.

Comment: As someone who has used pillow a fair amount, I do tend to think it is less-intuitive and certainly less-powerful than Mathematica. It is nice to know that it exists and get some sense for how to use it for when you lose that academic Mathematica license and the cost is prohibitive, but as they say, "use the right tool for the job" and for maybe the first time ever, the right tool is Mathematica. I do enjoy numpy, though, as a stand in for Mathematica arrays. It is often *much* more efficient.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Actually I was really reluctant to write up this post days ago as I love Mathematica to death. However, I feel helpless now and then if I want to communicate my research outcome with others in Mathematica. As long as WRI stays with their current business model, it is hopeless to see new blood flowing into the Mathematica usership, not to mention discipline-specific python packages are moving really fast : I personally interact with atmospheric models a lot and feel Mathematica lacks essential tools to deal with those tools.

Comment: I won't deny any of that. Modern research is done is python (and some R and MATLAB) and Mathematica has decidedly abdicated its once considerable position in that. My sole argument was about image processing with Mathematica vs. pillow. In that specific case, Mathematica still outperforms python in usability and performance.