# Using list of rules from imported .mat file

Tags: import, matlab

I'm attempting to learn Mathematica to replace MATLAB. However, I have some data in .mat files which contains named variables.

[image]

Whenever I import the .mat file, I get a list of rules. What's the best way to go about using these? Let's say I wanted to plot some of the LabeledData, say "n2_den". Would I do something like `ListLinePlot[data]/.n2_den`? Or would I be better off just converting the list of rules to a list like one of the recommendations shows when I import?

Comment: Turn it into an `Association`. That's the equivalent to the structure arrays (`struct`) in _Matlab_. Btw., see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/181501) for more hints on how to transplate between _Matlab_ and _Mathematica_.

Comment: I really like this suggestion [Henrick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38178/henrik-schumacher)! I makes a lot of sense in how to now use the data I've imported.

Comment: I am glad that this helped you.  Welcome on Mathematica.StackExchange and have fun with _Mahematica_!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case (in a verbose style to clarify structure):

```
mydata = {earth_alts -> {{3}, {4}, {5}}};

myEarthAltsData = mydata[[1, 2]]
```

Here, `mydata[[1,2]]` takes the second part of the (first) association, i.e., gives just the list of values.

Comment: That works great, thanks! Just as a follow-up then, what does it mean doing mydata[[1,2]] in terms of rules? I get the indexing in thinking about multidimensional lists, but not rules necessarily.

Comment: @Bo, the this axiom of _Mathematica_ is: ["Everything is an expression."](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html). And expressions are basically trees into which you can index with `Part` (`[[...]]`). In case of `mydata[[1,2]]` have a look at the internal representations by executing `TreeForm[mydata]` and `TreeForm[mydata[[1, 2]]]`. Do you see the pattern?

Comment: That's a really neat way to visualize what's happening here, thanks for pointing it out @HenrikSchumacher!

Answer (score 0):

Turn it into an `Association`. That's the equivalent to the structure arrays (struct) in *Matlab*.

Btw., see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/181501) for more hints on how to translate between *Matlab* and *Mathematica*.